# Sort a file while grouping indented lines with their parent (multiple level)

Tags: text-processing, sort

All the levels should be sorted alphabetically (but must be kept with their parent)

File Example:

```
first
    apple
    orange
        train
        car
    kiwi
third
    orange
    apple
        plane
second
    lemon
```

Expected Result:

```
first
    apple
    kiwi
    orange
        car
        train
second
    lemon
third
    apple
        plane
    orange
```

The following command has been used but it works only if the file has only two levels into the tree.

```
sed '/^[^[:blank:]]/h;//!G;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\x02\1/' infile | sort | sed 's/.*\x02//'
```

How can I do to sort all the levels correctly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: please format your input content in proper way (as it actually looks). Copy and paste, then use `{}` (code sample) on selected fragment

Comment: could the file have more than 3 levels?

Comment: 4 levels are possible

Comment: are there spaces before `first`, `second` (1st level) values?

Comment: No Spaces before the first level values

Comment: It's worth mentioning if this were a directory tree, all you would need would be `find .`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extended **`Python`** solution:

Sample `infile` contents (4 levels):

```
first
    apple
    orange
        train
        car
            truck
            automobile
    kiwi
third
    orange
    apple
        plane
second
    lemon
```

---

**`sort_hierarchy.py`** script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import re

with open(sys.argv[1], 'rt') as f:
    pat = re.compile(r'^\s+')
    paths = []

    for line in f:
        offset = pat.match(line)
        item = line.strip()

        if not offset:
            offset = 0
            paths.append(item)
        else:
            offset = offset.span()[1]
            if offset > prev_offset:
                paths.append(paths[-1] + '.' + item)
            else:
                cut_pos = -prev_offset//offset
                paths.append('.'.join(paths[-1].split('.')[:cut_pos]) + '.' + item)

        prev_offset = offset

    paths.sort()
    sub_pat = re.compile(r'[^.]+\.')
    for i in paths:
        print(sub_pat.sub(' ' * 4, i))
```

---

Usage:

```
python sort_hierarchy.py path/to/infile
```

The output:

```
first
    apple
    kiwi
    orange
        car
            automobile
            truck
        train
second
    lemon
third
    apple
        plane
    orange
```

Comment: @nick10, learn about [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

**`Awk`** solution:

Sample `infile` contents (4 levels):

```
first
    apple
    orange
        train
        car
            truck
            automobile
    kiwi
third
    orange
    apple
        plane
second
    lemon
```

---

```
awk '{
         offset = gsub(/ /, "");
         if (offset == 0) { items[NR] = $1 }
         else if (offset > prev_ofst) { items[NR] = items[NR-1] "." $1 }
         else {
             prev_item = items[NR-1];
             gsub("(\\.[^.]+){" int(prev_ofst / offset) "}$", "", prev_item);
             items[NR] = prev_item "." $1
         }
         prev_ofst = offset;
     }
     END{
         asort(items);
         for (i = 1; i <= NR; i++) {
             gsub(/[^.]+\./, "    ", items[i]);
             print items[i]
         }
     }' infile
```

---

The output:

```
first
    apple
    kiwi
    orange
        car
            automobile
            truck
        train
second
    lemon
third
    apple
        plane
    orange
```

Answer (score 0):

works for any depth

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
lines = open('test_file').read().splitlines()

def yield_sorted_lines(lines):
        sorter = []
        for l in lines:
                fields = l.split('\t')
                n = len(fields)
                sorter = sorter[:n-1] + fields[n-1:]
                yield sorter, l


prefixed_lines = yield_sorted_lines(lines)
sorted_lines = sorted(prefixed_lines, key=lambda x: x[0])
for x, y in sorted_lines:
        print(y)
```

Or an pipeline

```
awk -F'\\t' '{a[NF]=$NF; for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) printf "%s%s", a[i], i==NF? "\n": "\t"}' file|
sort | awk -F'\\t' -vOFS='\t' '{for (i=1; i<NF; ++i) $i=""; print}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/^ /{H;$!d};x;1d;s/\n/\x7/g' | sort | tr \\a \\n
```

The `/continuation/{H;$!d};x;1d` (or `/firstline/!`etc) is a slurp, it falls through only when it's got a complete line gaggle in the buffer.

If you might get a single-line gaggle at the end, add `${p;x;/\n/d}` to do the double-pump needed for that.